# Accidentally deleted etc/fstab

Tags: grub2, filesystem

etc/fstab accidentally edited or deleted, I don't know. Please someone help me to solve this. I am new to Ubuntu.

```
General error mounting filesystem.
A maintenance shell will now be started.
CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and reboot the system
```

More info:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes 
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders 
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes 
Disk identifier: 0x0005a46f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1 *             1       74697   599999489    5  Extended Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary. 
/dev/sda2           75195      100094   200000512   83  Linux 
/dev/sda3           74697       75195     3999744   82  Linux swap / Solaris 
/dev/sda4          100094      121602   172761088   83  Linux 
/dev/sda5               1       31124   249999360   83  Linux
/dev/sda6           31124       62248   249999360   83  Linux 
/dev/sda7           62248       64738    19998720   83  Linux 
/dev/sda8           64738       69717    39999488   83  Linux 
/dev/sda9           69718       74573    38999040   83  Linux 
/dev/sda10          74573       74697      998400   83  Linux
```

Comment: someone help me to solve this

Comment: As said earlier, we need more info. What's the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda` and how many hard drives do you have?

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0005a46f

Comment: Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       74697   599999489    5  Extended
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda2           75195      100094   200000512   83  Linux
/dev/sda3           74697       75195     3999744   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4          100094      121602   172761088   83  Linux
/dev/sda5               1       31124   249999360   83  Linux

Comment: /dev/sda6           31124       62248   249999360   83  Linux
/dev/sda7           62248       64738    19998720   83  Linux
/dev/sda8           64738       69717    39999488   83  Linux
/dev/sda9           69718       74573    38999040   83  Linux
/dev/sda10          74573       74697      998400   83  Linux

Comment: some one help to slove this

Answer (score 0):

To solve ur problem you need a ubuntu live usb/cd . boot into ubuntu from cd/usb and open terminal and command blkid note UUID no of your ubuntu partition and swap.
if your ubuntu and swap partitions dont show up then mount them and try again.

after noting uuid no's go to your ubuntu partition and go to etc/ and create a empty document named fstab

copy the below two line starting with uuid in that fstab

> UUID=xxxx /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

replace the above xxxx with your noted UUID no of ubuntu partition

> UUID=xxxx none            swap    sw              0       0

replace this xxxx with swap uuid no

and after that reboot

still no good then boot into ubuntu live usb once more and install boot-repair and run boot repair

i hope that helps

Comment: same problem :- General error mounting filesystem. A maintenance shell will now be started. CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and reboot the system

Comment: boot from live usb/cd and try installing boot-repair here is how to do that http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Comment: now it's working properly when boots up it asking for password entering correct password it will bring me back to log in screen

Comment: did you use boot-repair

Comment: no i solve it from doing like this mount -t ext4 -o rw,remount /dev/sda1 /   and echo "UUID=52e062e0-716c-4828-9bf1-05b93fdaef93 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1" > /etc/fstab

Comment: someone help me to solve this ...

Comment: what your problem not solved ???

Comment: no. now giving correct password also bringing me to login screen

Comment: can you login into console ctrl+Alt+F1 if you can check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop

Comment: after login to console i have try to install package and getting this type SUDO:effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root ?

Comment: how to solve this two problem  SUDO:effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root ? and  next problem is giving the password correct also bringing me to login screen only please someone help me to solve

Comment: You should post it as another question so that others can see it and give answer

Comment: please try to how give me solution how to fix.